# Solidity struct and staking code error: Please look into the contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I had built a staking contract but while testing the staking it's throwing `The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.` this error. My code is
`

```
function startGame(address secondPlayer, string memory phrase, uint _amount) external { 

require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount); uint _stakedAmountChallenger = stakeZug(_amount);
    uint secret =uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(phrase)));

matchLists.push(matchUps(matchStatus.Start,msg.sender,secondPlayer,_stakedAmountChallenger,0,_stakedAmountChallenger,secret,false));
                uint gameNumber = matchLists.length -1;
                isValid[gameNumber] = true;
                emit challengeInitiator(msg.sender, secondPlayer, false, gameNumber);
            }
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Add the 'payable' specifier to the function description:

function startGame(...) external payable {

Comment: why it should be a payable can you explain please

Comment: You have not shown how you call this function, but the error message directly says:"...The called function should be payable.."

Comment: But there is no transfer function in the function please look at it...And its not a problem of the payable function only....

Comment: First, write how you send the transaction causing the error. The answer is given according to the information you provided in the question.